# Multi Language Implementation Option

Tags: octobercms, laravel-5.5

Respected All

I have upgraded my website from Laravel 5.4 to Laravel 5.5 and I found it very very useful far to work in Laravel.

Recently, I faced a problem. I am asked to implement two languages in the website written in Laravel which has around 30 pages in Admin and around 45 web pages in End user side.

I have 3 option.

> 1. Create resource files in resources/lang/
> 2. Create tables like Language, Modules and Messages based on Module and based on Language.
> 3. Should I use October CMS?

If there is any better option, Please suggest.

Best Regards

Pankaj Garg

Comment: You should try the OctoberCMS, it's a very powerful CMS and you can find plenty of tutorials on the YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

the fastest solution is create language files and replace all hardcoded strings through language keys because you only have 2 languages

but

i would use octoberCMS with

[Rainlab Translate](https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-translate)

its a very nice plugin that makes the step easier if you want to extend the languages

Answer (score 0):

Please use below plugin for translation for the October CMS site:

https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-translate

Reference Video: https://vimeo.com/102449697 for how to use **Rainlab Translate** plugin.